# melody starting point on song parts

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, melody, songwriting

Hi I'm writing a song in a Bb Major key
and the chords goes something like
EbM7 , F7 , Gm7 
and the first note of the melody starts with G note. (this is the main chorus part)

And if the verse part starts with the Bb above the G note, is it weird ?
since normally chorus is the highest part of the song ?
if there is other cases like mine
let me know !
thanks !

Comment: There are no rules, it's not weird, it's your song, write what you like. Choruses are not 'normally the highest'. If you like what you've written try it out on others. That's a far better test.

Comment: @Tim then do you know any other songs that are like what I said ??

Answer (score 1):

As G is the 6th of Bb, this will give it a Bb6 chord. It sounds like it may sound good!

Comment: Are you sure G is the 7th of B-flat? It seems to me that G is just a sixth above B-flat!

Comment: this is the scale B♭, C, D, E♭, F, G, the Bb chord is B♭, D, F and the 6th is G; you are right my bad. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've heard several songs where the chorus is sung in a lower range than the verses, and in pop especially it's not impossible to find songs that do what you've done. The reason why typically it isn't done often is that the chorus is usually high-energy compared to the verse, and it's hard to convey that energy in a lower range.

Examples? Michael Jackson's "Don't Stop 'Til You Get Enough" has a higher range in its verse than chorus (but it's pretty close). "Staying Alive" by the Bee Gees is also very close, but most parts are higher in the chorus. Taylor Swift's "Bad Blood" is a current example, as well as "This is America" by Childish Gambino (this is more common in rap/hip hop, as the transitions from verses to choruses often are decreasing in energy).There are many other examples, I just don't know of any way to easily research that statistic.

Generally, it's not common in genres where the chorus is usually a climax of energy; however, some, like rap/hip hop, often have verses as the important parts of the songs.